# how to open an existing debugfs directory from a kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have a driver that is integrated with kernel and is creating a debug folder and couple of files. I have a test framework for the same driver, which is built as a module and when the test framework's .`ko` is insmoded, I would like it to create couple of more files under the same `debugfs` folder. Now the question is, I see only `debugfs_create_dir()` API and not an API to open an existing `debugfs`
( I need to open it to get the dentry handle which will be used in creating the new files in that directory).

Answer (score 0):

You must create debugfs files only in your own directory, and you already got that one's dentry when you called `debugfs_create_dir()`.

Comment: I'm the owner of both the driver as well as test framework. If I want to use the same directory created by driver in my test framework, I should get the dentry pointer right ? how can I get that ? BTW, there is no API in my driver that exposes this to test framework.

Comment: You need an API in your driver that exposes this to test framework.